# ProGet unauthenticted feeds; no user/password required

Tags: nuget-server, proget

Is it possible to create an unauthenticated nuget feed in ProGet where user credentials do not have to be supplied to access the feed?

Comment: John provided details as to what I needed, however, to get this to work fully, I had to enable Anonymous authentication on the website in IIS and disable Windows authentication.  Once I did that, the site behaves as you would expect.  No login prompts to access the site, but login when performing admin duties.  This also allowed anonymous feed access in 

I'm not sure if this is a leftover affect from enabling and then disabling LDAP or not, but I will confirm this with a clean install on a test VM.

Comment: You are correct and I will add to my answer; I had just assumed you were using the built-in web server which does not require that extra setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just grant the default "View Only" role to the Anonymous user. If you're using LDAP authentication, then grant that role to the "Everyone" group.

Also note that if you running ProGet through IIS, you must enable Anonymous Authentication or else every unauthenticated request will receive a 401 authentication challenge.

Comment: Hmm, I switched back to normal users, non-LDAP, and it seems that ProGet is stuck in a limbo mode of 1/2 LDAP and 1/2 normal user.

I still get prompted for AD creds to hit the website as well as VS for feed access.

I restarted the ProGet Windows Service as well as recycled the AppPool and restarted the website.

I can no longer post nuget packages to proget:

Failed to process request. 'There was an error processing the request: API Key not set; must specify username:password as API Key.'. 

...even though I am supplying username:password in the format as specified in the documentation.

Comment: cannot edit my own comments...publish works fine, that was a build server issue.  I still have the issue or seemingly the site is sorta left in a previous AD mode for auth.  suggestions?

Comment: Example, when hitting the ProGet site from a server that has never loaded the site before, a user/password dialog is prompted. Anything can be entered, the site loads.  If trying to access management features, a login page appears. Login honors built-in users (not ldap; turned off).

Anonymous access to feeds still does not work.  401 Unauthorized is returned (trying this in LINQPad).  Visual Studio prompts with LDAP login prefilled in user/password dialog. The prefilled user does not work.  Using the existing Admin user allows the feed to be pulled from Visual Studio. think i'm almost there.

Comment: The Everyone group is not showing in my list when using LDAP and the site 401s when I access using nuget commandline.